# command line variable/string

Tags: c#

My code looks something like this, but I have shortened it a little.

```
public static void mainvoid()
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (line == "restart")
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Main();
    }
    if (line == "enter a value: ")
    {
        string value = console.ReadLine();
        console.writeline("Your value is {0}", value);
        mainvoid();
    }
    if (line == "my name")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0}",     ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.name);
        mainvoid();
    }
```

I want my program to pick up a command (witch I have done) and some of them have values/strings after them E.g.
By the way I am using c# 2010
I want my command to look like this

> My name is Daniel
> and so the string/value = Daniel
> or
> name = billy
> so the string/value = billy

So I want it to pick it up via console.readline(); and pick out that it is changing the name and after that will be the name in which it will be changed to.

But I don't know how to make the last bit the value/string that I can also use.

Please leave a comment if you can help me :)

Comment: wont is different from want. Please get it right.

Comment: @nawfal StackOverflow is an open platform, like a wiki, you can easily edit someone's question to fix spelling errors, rather than leaving useless comments. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Comment: @MattDavey Anyone can fix it easily (and that's what I did), but that doesn't mean one shouldn't guide a person to get some rudimentary stuffs correct. OP not making this mistake one more time is most important for himself. Once I corrected the spelling mistakes, OP re-edited the question again with the same mistakes where all my "want"s were made "wont"s again. I had to re-re-edit again. How easier and appropriate it is just to teach him forever in that case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that there are two issues here, one is extracting the persons name from the "my name is xyz" command, the other is saving that value for later in the program.

Because of the way you've structured your `mainmethod`, and the fact that it calls itself (this is called recursion), it cannot share any variables from one call to the next. This makes it impossible to store the persons name. You could eliminate the recursion by instead creating a loop in the `mainmethod`

```
static public void Main()
{
    string currentLine;

    do
    {
        currentLine = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    while (!currentLine.Equals("exit"))
}
```

This will continuously allow the user to enter commands, and the program will terminate when the user enters "exit".

Now onto the problem of storing the users name, you can simply remove the "my name is" part of the sentence to get the users name...

```
static public void Main()
{
    string username = "Matthew";

    string currentLine;

    do
    {
        currentLine = Console.ReadLine();

        if (currentLine.Equals("restart"))
        {
            Console.Clear();
        }

        if (currentLine.StartsWith("my name is"))
        {
            username = currentLine.Replace("my name is ", "");
        }

        if (currentLine.Equals("my name"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0}", username);
        }
    }
    while (!currentLine.Equals("exit"))
}
```

I hope that gets you moving!

Comment: thanks allot Matt it works great on a test new project, will try and put it into my main project now :D

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to come up with your own syntax.

For e.g i have chosen a syntax like below

```
<Command Name>:Parameters    
ChangeName:Daniel
```

Then have a enum to define your commands

```
enum Command
{
      ChangeName
}
```

//Now we can parse the command and take a required action

```
//Split the string
String[] inputs= Console.ReadLine().Split(":");//"ChangeName:Bob"

//Generate the enumeration type from the input command
var cmd = (Command) Enum.Parse(typeof(Command), inputs[0] , false);

if(cmd == Command.ChangeName)
{
//Process the parameters in inputs[1]
}
```

Comment: Do you think this is overcomplicating things a little bit?

Comment: yeah.. I can see this is a good extensible solution and I would probably do something similar myself, but the OP is clearly new to C# so I'm just wondering if it might be a bit over the top for him..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pick up command by `Console.ReadLine()` pick it with `Console.ReadKey(true)`. Your text won't change.

Here is example:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo ck = Console.ReadKey(true);
if(ck.Key == Keys.Space){
//do something
}
```

I didn't understand you well, but I'll try guess :)

If you want to retrive the name, you may write like this:

```
Console.Write("Your name is ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: i wont the command to produce a value after it for example: Bob

Comment: JesseJames, i know about that code but i don't wont it like that... i wont it in the same line as the code, e.g. MYNAME = james and james will be the string...